# How get only need files from HDFS?

Tags: scala, hadoop, filesystems, hdfs

I have method getAllFiles:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{LocatedFileStatus, Path}

  def getAllDLFiles: Iterator[LocatedFileStatus] = {

    val hadoopConfig = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
    val isCsvFile    = (_ : LocatedFileStatus).getPath.getName.endsWith(".csv")
    val allFiles     = path.getFileSystem(hadoopConfig)
                           .listFiles(path, true)
                           .filter(isCsvFile)
    allFiles
  }
```

This method reads all files from the directory. Then it applies a filter returning only csv files.

But I want to apply the filter right away. Before he returns all the files. Please help me.
I know that there is a special class for this in the Hadoop file system library - PathFilter. But I didn't figure out how to work with it.

Comment: A PathFilter would work the same way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is much of a difference because it still iterates all the NameNode entries. Also, you don't need Spark to do this

In Java,

```
FileSystem fileSystem = Filesystem.get(new Configuration());
for (FileStatus fileStatus : fileSystem.globStatus(new Path("/path/to/data/*"), new PathFilter() {

    public boolean accept(Path path) {
        return path.toString().matches("\\.csv$");
    }
    System.out.println(fileStatus);
}
```

But with Spark, you'd can do `spark.read.format("csv").path("/path/to/data/")` to read all the CSVs, assuming you don't care about the filenames and want to actually read the data